# GVim/Vim. How to delete all white space up to a certain word

Tags: vim

I'm a .Net dev but recently started dabbling with Vim (or in my instance GVim) for when I need to do repetitive text editor type tasks.

My experience is basically non-existent. So please bear with me. Also I realize there are GUI tools or things I can make use of inside Visual Studio, but I'm trying out the Vim route as I'd like to master a new util/app every now and then.

Say I've got a text file which contains a lot of properties (could be any text though) like so:

> ```
>     public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
>
>     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
>
>     public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
>
>     public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
>
>     public string OfferDate { get; set; }
> ```

I'd like to make use of the string replace method to delete everything up to, and after the property name.

e.g. end with:

```
 AccountNumber, 
 CustomerName, ... etc.
```

So far I've had success with

> - 1) Alt + left click + drag select all the preceding white space &    delete
> - 2) :% s/public\ string\ //
> - 3)  :% s/\ {\ get;\ set;\ }/,/

It's purely out of curiosity I'd like to find out if its possible to update my 2nd step to include the removal of the white space.

I realize the ^ character means beginning of the line and that (I think) \s means white space, but that's about where my knowledge ends.

I'm thinking something like?

> :% s/^\s+string//

Comment: are lines always starting with `public string`? that could make answer simpler.. also always match pattern `<spaces>public string TARGET {trashhere}`?

Comment: well in my example yes, but i'd just like to see how i'd have to go about basic ideas such as this. I'm finding this whole vim thing very intriguing. So it's definitely on my to learn list. (as it'll help improve my regex as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this,

```
%s/^\v\s*(\s*\w+){2}\s?(\w+).*/\2/g
```

precisely speaking, this line doesn't know which word is your "property". it just leave the 3rd word in the line there, remove anything else.

Comment: I wish i could accept both answers. But thank you & @FredrikPihl

Answer (score 3):

one way to solve this is to record a macro

```
qq          # start recording macro into register q
0w          # move to first non-whitespace caracter. Omit this if no WS at start of line
d2w         # delete 2 words
w           # move a word forward
D           # delete to en of line 
q           # quit macro recording
```

standing at the beginning of a line, do `@q`
For subsequent lines, repeat the macro using `.`

or, try the following substitution

```
:%s/^\s*public string\s*\([a-zA-Z]*\).*$/\1/
```

Comment: I've managed to do this with a macro as well, but, and I probably should have clarified that I'm specifically looking to find out if this is possible using the scripts available?

Comment: @Kent - jupp, question seemed to have pretty defined strings. But I agree, your regex is a lot more general and better

Comment: @FredrikPihl :) I thought OP didn't explain it. so that would be a question to OP, not comment on an answer. I don't want to be picky... :)

Comment: Now comes the comment to your answer..picky? ^_^.. OP's example has spaces at the beginning of each line, I don't know if those spaces are in text, if yes, `d2w` won't work (if cursor sits at col0`. If this is not the case, after `d2w`, you `w` will skip all spaces before the `{`, so doesn't fit `delete everything up to`.... I would +1 your answer anyway after we clear about this...

Comment: You ARE picky :-) but yes, if the line starts with ws, I updated answer to include a `0w` to move to the first definition of a word for the macro to work

Comment: @FredrikPihl oh...so sad to hear that.... :,,(...  in fact I thought macro at the beginning, didn't manage to make it work. because `0w` won't work for no beginning spaces lines.... the latter `w` could be fix by `el` maybe.. anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `:normal` would be an alternative to `:s` or a macro in this case:

```
:%norm 03dwelD
```

You may want to use a different range other than the whole file, `%`. I would suggest visually selecting the lines with `V` then execute `:norm 03dwelD`. After you type `:` your prompt will look like `:'<,'>`. This is correct.

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
```